# How to talk with main thread swift files to access main thread variables

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, uiwebview

I am a very experienced Android dev but very new to iOS dev using swift. Right now I have setup a UIWebview and a NSURLProtocol using canInitWithRequest (2 separate swift files). The canInitWithRequest method works great but I need to acccess the UIWebview object in order to call functions on the UIWebview object.

For example. if request == google.com then UIWebview.something().

In Android in order to talk with the Main activity thread I just simply create a interface, implement it in my main thread and now I have access to everything on that main activity class.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Starter: http://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1

Comment: Threads don't really come into it. It is just standard object oriented programming, the same in Java, C#, Objective-C or Swift;  objects need to have references to one another to interact (or you can use some sort of messaging like NSNotificationCenter but I don't think that is what you want here). It doesn't sound like good program design for the `canInitWithRequest` function to start loading a request - the word "can" implies that it should return a Boolean. Some other code should do that.  `if canInit(req) then load(req)` sort of thing

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for the method `-webView(_:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:)` in the [`UIWebViewDelegate` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:).

By implementing this interface, you can have a different object (e.g. the object in your "separate Swift file") determine whether or not to load an `NSURLRequest` and even do run custom behavior first:

```
extension MyObject: UIWebViewDelegate {
    func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        if request.URL == NSURL(string: "google.com") {
            // Do your custom behavior...
            webView.something()
        }
        // Allow the webView to load the request
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will not pick ajax calls. We load all of our pages via async calls. shouldStartLoadWithRequest picks up only postbacks